# How to verify static method call using Moq

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407038/moqing-static-method-call-to-c-sharp-library-class) I have made my static method calls an `Action` in the hope that I can set and verify the call in my Moq unit test.

The code being tested is:

```
public Action<Data> Calculate = x => CalculatorHelper.Calculate(x);

public void CalculateData(Data data)
{
    ...

    Calculate(data);

    ...
}
```

And the test is:

```
[Test]
public void CalculateIsCalled()
{
    _mockService.Setup(x => x.Calculate = CalculatorHelper.Calculate)
                .Verifiable();
    ...

    _mockService.VerifyAll();
}
```

However, the parameter in the `Setup()` is throwing the compile error "an expression tree cannot contain an assignment operator".

Obviously the code `x => x.Calculate = CalculatorHelper.Calculate` is incorrect but what would the correct way to code this?

Comment: is assignment should look like `public Action<Data> Calculate =  CalculatorHelper.Calculate;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Calculate` should return a new Action pointing to `CalculatorHelper.Calculate`, so it should be:

```
_mockService.Setup(x => x.Calculate).Returns(CalculatorHelper.Calculate)
            .Verifiable();
```

However, for this to work, `Calculate` needs to be a `virtual` property, not just a field.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that `Calculate` is public field, you don't even need Moq here (also assuming you are testing that `CalculateData` calls the delegate):

```
Data passedAsActionParameter = null;
var testedClass = new Calculator();
testedClass.Calculate = d => { passedAsActionParameter = d; };
var data = new Data();
testedClass.CalculateData(data);

Assert.That(passedAsActionParameter, Is.EqualTo(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll test that out later!